# What is the difference when we use <>() or <'Name of a wrapper class'>() and () only when declaring any type of data structure in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have seen plenty of times how when declaring a data structure only round brackets are used while doing the dynamic allocation and many times, we have to include the wrapper class's name inside the Angle brackets? What's the major difference in these two declarations?

E.g.

```
HashSet<String> h = new HashSet();
```

and

```
LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: The difference is, for example, that the first way won't work. I suppose you meant `new HashSet<>();`?

Comment: The diamond operator `<>` was added in Java 7 and you should [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2970947). `Set<String> h = new HashSet<>();` and `List<String> l = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: BTW - `HashSet<String> h = new HashSet();` will work, just with a compiler warning "unchecked conversion"